# How to extract text based on font color inside a cell in "Google sheets" with text of multiple colors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

does anyone know how to extract the "*colored*" part of the content inside a single cell in google sheets via the *apps script*? Attaching a screenshot for an example. Would be very helpful if you could point me to relevant resources. #sheet #appsscript [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBViH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can access formatted text using [`getRichTextValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value). From this you can create an array of "runs", where:

> *each run is the longest possible substring having a consistent text style.*

From there you can inspect the foreground color of each run.

For example, assuming this:

[image]

You can access any text which is not black (represented by `#000000`):

```js
function getTextColors() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const richText = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2").getRichTextValue();
  console.log( richText );
  richText.getRuns().forEach((element) => {
    var txt = element.getText();
    var txtColor = element.getTextStyle().getForegroundColor();
    if (txtColor !== '#000000') {
      console.log(txt, txtColor)
    }
  } )
}
```

This prints:

```
fox #00ff00
over  #ff0000
```

An overview of the color codes used can be found [here](https://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm).

---

If you prefer, you can use `getForegroundColorObject()` instead of `getForegroundColor()` - and then handle the resulting [`Color`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/color) object.